# How to use PHP to populate a <select> Dropdown with json data

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to populate a  dropdown using php and a json file. It should get populated with all of the "Name" values. If I use:

```
$printers=file_get_contents ("config/printers.json");
$test= json_decode($printers,true);
foreach($test as $test) {
    echo $test['Name'];
}
```

It will display the correct values so I know the json is correct and using correct call to get the data.
(updated)If I use this as suggested I get an error "Fatal error, Uncaught TypeError: cannot access offset of type string on string in:" and points to the echo call.

```
<select id="printer" name="printer">
<option value="none">Select Printer</option>
<?php 
foreach($test as $t) {
   echo '<option value="'. $t['Name'].  '">'. $t['Name'].'</option>';      
  }
?>
</select>
```

But if I change it to (which is probably wrong):

```
<select id="printer" name="printer">
        <option value="none">Select Printer</option>
        <?php 
          foreach($test as $t) {
            echo '<option value="'. $test['Name'].  '">'. $test['Name'].'</option>';      
          }
        ?>
    </select>
```

The error goes away and the dropdown will get populated but with only 5 entries. (there are 20 elements in the array) and all 5 entries are the last item in the array.
<strike>I think I am missing something in escaping the quotes correctly?</strike> This part seems to be resolved?

The json file is:

```
[
    {
      "Name": "CR-10",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-10 V2",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-10 Mini",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-10S",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-10S4",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-10S5",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""     
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-10S Pro",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-10S Pro V2",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-10 Max",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "CR-20",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ender 3",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ender 3X",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ender 3 V2",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ender 3 Pro",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ender 3 Pro/BLV Mod",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ender 5",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ender 5 Pro",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ender 5 Plus",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Voxelab Aquila",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    },
    {
      "Name": "Anet ET4/ET5",
      "GantryStyle": 1,
      "comment": "",
      "image": "cr-10.jpg",
      "option1": ""      
    }
  ]
```

Comment: foreach $test as $test? You should call $test as $t maybe with a different variable name

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the problem specifically is. And you haven't provided any sample JSON so we can't entirely predict what the code will do.  Please update the question

Comment: Actually, you seem to be mistaken. `foreach($test as $t) {
   echo '<option value="'. $t['Name'].  '">'. $t['Name'].'</option>';      
  }`. works perfectly well as you'd expect - demo: https://3v4l.org/tRtsG . It's not clear how you got it to generate the error you're claiming

Comment: Whereas `foreach($test as $t) {
            echo '<option value="'. $test['Name'].  '">'. $test['Name'].'</option>';      
          }` doesn't produce only 5 entries as you claim, it actually produces 20 empty options, and 40 warnings about an undefined array key which is, again, as you'd expect. Demo: https://3v4l.org/cjSH3 . It's mystifying how you've got the result you stated. Either you're not running the code you're showing us, or you're not testing with the data you've shown...or maybe even both. Voting to close the question as the error is not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was not the entire code and I should have reduced my test code to match what I posted. There was an error introduced in earlier code. Thanks for the help!
Go ahead and close it. I couldn't see how to close it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `'` and `"` together:

```
  <select id="printer" name="printer">
        <option value="none">Select Printer</option>
        <?php 
          foreach($test as $t) {
            echo '<option value="'. $t['Name'].  '">'. $t['Name'].'</option>';      
          }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: That formatting "looks" better but it still doesn't work and in the dev tool it states: "Fatal error, Uncaught TypeError: cannot access offset of type string on string in... and references this line:
           
 echo '<option value="'. $t['Name'].  '">'. $t['Name'].'</option>';

Comment: you may use $t->Name